# Solving an Ordinary Differential Equation for a complex function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

What is the solution to the ODE 
$$zf'(z)+\lambda f(z)-c = z(z+i)^{-(\lambda +2)}$$ where $f$ is a complex function, $\lambda$ is a complex number and c is an arbitrary constant. i is the usual complex number. Also $z\in\mathbb{U}$, the upper half of the complex plane.

Comment: $(z^λf(z))'=z^λz(z+i)^{-(λ+2)}$ if you specify a domain where a branch for both powers can be specified, like $\Bbb C\setminus(\Bbb R_-\cup(-i+\Bbb R_i))$ or some other construction connecting the branching points $0,-i$ to infinity.

Comment: The domain is the upper half of the complex plane $\mathbb{U} = \{z\in \mathbb{C}: \Im(z)>0\}$

Comment: Yes, that works as it excludes the branching points.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Such function is analytic, i.e. of the form $$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k.$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the use of the main branch of all powers $w^a=\exp(a\,{\rm Ln}(w))$ on $\Bbb U$ for uniqueness, one finds
$$
(z^λf(z))'=\frac{z^λ}{(z+i)^{λ+2}}=\frac1{(z+i)^2}\left(1-\frac{i}{z+i}\right)^λ
=-\frac{i}{λ+1}\frac{d}{dz}\left(1-\frac{i}{z+i}\right)^{λ+1}
$$
which can now be integrated to
$$
z^λf(z)=-\frac{i}{λ+1}\left(\frac{z}{z+i}\right)^{λ+1}+C.
$$

The modified equation can be solved similarly, it just contains additionally the integral of $cz^{λ-1}$ on the right side.

Comment: What if I have a case that includes the branching points. For instance:  $$zf'(z)+\lambda f(z)-c = (z-i)^{-(\lambda +1)}$$ where $f$ is a complex function, $\lambda$ is a complex number and c is an arbitrary constant. i is the usual complex number. Also $z\in\mathbb{U}$, the upper half of the complex plane.

Comment: The basic question remains, what is $(z-i)^λ$ around $z=i$? If $λ/pi$ is irrational, then the possible values of all branches form a dense set on the circle of radius $|z-i|^λ$.

Comment: Actually we expect $\lambda$ to be pure imaginary. If $z=i$, then $(z-i)^{\lambda}=0$. I thought that definitely around that point the quantity is approaching zero

Comment: How would we write the solution?

Comment: If you do not have a well-defined equation, you can not speak of solutions. Expressions with complex exponents are even less well-defined.